# Building strace for an older Linux system that does not have a build environment

Tags: gcc, libc

I have a bit of a problem.  I need to use the strace utility to figure out why a command is crashing on an older Linux system.  Unfortunately, I don't have strace nor do I have gcc/binutils on that system.

I tried building the app statically on a current Debian system, but calls to getpwnam require a dynamic load of the version of libc that was used at compile time.  That would be fine, but being that the utilities on the older system were all built using an ancient version of libc, putting a newer libc on that system breaks everything else.

Short of downloading and installing an old distribution of Linux and then doing the build, is there an easier way around this problem?  The original distribution on this system is currently unknown and the more I research it, it's getting to seem like a huge chicken vs egg problem.  Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to follow up on my query, I ultimately took an educated guess as to what distribution it was, then had to work backwards through the releases until I had a system with the same version of libc.  Once I did that, I could compile the utility I needed (strace).

Answer (score 0):

Using an outdated Linux system is never wise... can it be upgraded? If not, why not? What is failing, and how? Any chance of updating that?

There should be a file named /etc/release or similar, that should give you an idea of the distribution and version. Or `uname -a` might give a clue on the distribution. If it doesn't work, try to see if commands like rpm, apt-get, or one of the other package management commands are available, that will narrow down the distribution. A Google search for some of the installed packages with versions might help narrow down the version of the distribution.

Knowing distribution and version you may be able to get strace (and perhaps other needed packages). Many distributions keep archival  versions (at least of the original installation media for old versions) around.

Comment: I would normally agree with you, but this is a vendor supplied, embedded system and I can't make the alterations you suggest.  My only choice here is to set up a build environment that can create a utility that runs on the target system.

Comment: Any chance of contacting the vendor for details? Under the GPL you are entitled to full source, so they should have at least that available. That would be a starting point, most embedded systems use idiosyncratic setups that aren't easy to assimilate to "normal" distributions.

Comment: The vendor isn't going to help me.  They're the paranoid type.  Thanks for the help, but I need a build environment - that's the only solution I've found so far.